# Force compiler to choose const operator overload

Tags: c++

I am trying to simulate a cache. When given an array, I have to determine if the `operator[](size_t i)` is used to get data or to set it. I've overloaded it with `const`in its signature for the get part and without it for the set part.

My problem is that since the array is dynamically allocated, only the non-const `operator[]` gets called. Eg:

```
    class A {    
            int n;
            double *v;
    public:
            A(int i) : n(i),v(new double[i]) {}   
            const double & operator[](int i) const {
                cout<<"get"<<endl ;
                return v[i];
            }   
            double& operator[](int i) {
                cout<<"set"<<endl;
                return v[i];
            }   
    };
    int main(){
        double pi = 3.14;
        A a(10);
        a[2] = pi;   
        pi = a[3];
    }
```

The result is

```
 set
 set
```

but I'm hoping to print

```
set
get
```

Comment: You will need separate functions then, because the choice of either the `const` or non-`const` function doesn't care about about what you're going to do with it. If you're calling it on a non-`const` object, you get the non-`const` version, and for a `const` object you get the `const` version. When you do `a[3]`, it doesn't know that you're not going to assign to it. It just calls the non-`const` function because `a` is not `const`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't have anything to do with the array being dynamically allocated. Your variable `a` is not `const`, so the non-`const` function will be called on it. If you had `const B b(10);` and did `b[3]`, the `const` version would be called.

If you really want to, you can force the `const` version to be called by casting to a `const` reference:

```
static_cast<const A&>(a)[3]
```

(Or alternatively, create a reference variable and call it on that)

Comment: But `b[2] = pi;` wont compile in that case

Comment: @user3371583 Of course, that's the whole point. Since the object is `const`, the `operator[]` should return a `const` reference to its internals, so you can't assign to it.

Answer (score 3):

You've discovered why `operator[]` is a poor 'interface' for cache-like operations, and also why everybody seems to be caught out by the behaviour of `std::map` which creates a new object if you try to 'index' one that doesn't exist.

I'd write explicit `get` and `set` methods, and that way you won't surprise users of your cache class.